# Why doesn't UIButton title display?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

In a UIViewController's viewDidLoad method, I do this:

```
UIButton *b = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] 
                                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

[b setTitle:@"Testing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b setTitleColor: [UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:b];                       // EDIT: should be 'b'
NSLog(@"button title: %@", [b titleLabel].text);
```

The button displays but the title doesn't.  The NSLog line prints "Testing" to the console.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Two ideas: * What happens if you make your button larger?
* Are you doing anything else in viewDidLoad that could be affecting the button?

Comment: Please see diederikh's solution below as it describes an error in the double initializer used above as well as the fix for it, which is to assign the frame separately, after the convenience initializer [... button with type ...] completes.  The rest of the OP's own solution is correct and remains the same.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I cannot tell you why it does not work, but I do have a solution:

```
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] ;        
b. frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

[b setTitle:@"Testing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b setTitleColor: [UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:b];
```

Seperate  creating the frame from the allocation and init of the button.

Comment: I agree. I bet chaining two initializers together like you're doing is causing some issues. Use the buttonWithType then set the frame.

Comment: Yeah, `buttonWithType` is a static factory method that returns a fully initialized button. You can't call `initWithFrame` on an already-initialized button (the result is at best undefined). `init` methods are only intended to be called after `alloc`.

Answer (score 22):

The problem lies with

```
UIButton *b = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] 
                                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

`buttonWithType` returns an autoreleased initialized object. You cannot send it an initWithFrame again as an object can only be initialized once.

Set its frame separately:

```
b.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this instead:

```
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
b.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[b setTitle:@"Testing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b setTitleColor: [UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:b];
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you have to go for `[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:]` or `[UIButton buttonWithType:]`, you should not use both together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
UIButton *b=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

`b=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];`

```
[b setTitle:@"Button Title Here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:b];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it ended up being the fact that I was setting the image rather than the backgroundImage. It all worked fine when I did:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```